# Pointer Arithmetic: how are these statements different?

Tags: c++, ios, c, pointers, xcode6

In IOS8.1, XCode 6.1.1 while working with some pointer arithmetic, I ran into a compiler error. After debugging, I came down to the following code snippet of lines that compile and lines that don't. I don't understand why the compiler interprets them differently:

```
struct kd_node_struct* find_median(struct kd_node_struct *startNode, struct kd_node_struct *endNode, int dimensionNumber)
{
    //these lines compile fine
    struct kd_node_struct *median = endNode - endNode + startNode;
    struct kd_node_struct *median2 = (startNode - endNode) / 2;
    struct kd_node_struct *median3 = startNode + ( (endNode - startNode) / 2);  

   //these lines give "invalid operands to binary expression" error
    struct kd_node_struct *median4 = endNode + endNode + startNode;
    struct kd_node_struct *median5 = (startNode + endNode) / 2;
}
```

Regardless of the what the statements actually evaluate to, I don't understand why these operations look different to the compiler. How is median different from median4, other than leading with a + or - operator? Same for median2 and median5. And I really don't see how median3 compiles, if median5 fails.

I find the error message particularly confusing...

```
Invalid operands to binary expression('struct kd_node_struct *' and 'struct kd_node_struct *')
```

...because that looks like two identical types to me.

What am I missing here?

*Edit: while median2 compiles, it does have a warning:

```
Incompatible integer to pointer conversion initializing 'struct kd_node_struct *' with an expression of type 'long'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> ...because that looks like two identical types to me.

Right, but adding pointers is a nonsensical operation, so the language doesn't allow it. Subtraction is fine.

> while median2 compiles, it does have a warning:

Right, because you've made an integer (pointer difference divided by two), and you're trying to initialize a pointer variable with it.

`median3` is the only correct/meaningful piece of code you have. `median1` Is syntactically correct, but is equivalent to `median = startnode`, which is probably not what you want.

Comment: I see. I suppose most pointer add operations are invalid. Still, I think I'd prefer the compiler let me decide if its something I really want to do or not. Thanks.

Comment: It's not the compiler, it's the language. And you can still do it, you just need to typecast first. Can you suggest a valid reason to do such a thing?

Comment: I view median5, from my example above, looking for the median address between the start and end of the array (as part of a KDTree evaluation) was a legit reason to add the two pointers. Thanks to your comments, though, I see how typecasting would have solved it, but I resorted to median3 in my code. It's just a personal preference that I think median3 is more readable than adding typecasts to median5. Thanks, your comments helped greatly.

Comment: P.S. Median5 is what started the whole saga. :) That's what I wanted to do in the first place, then didn't understand why it failed but median3 succeeded. After that, the rest were just experiments with the operators, looking for a pattern.